# Can I plug IBM Notes Applications into IBM Rational Synergy?

Tags: lotus-domino, configuration-management

A client of mine is trying to have all software tracked by his Configuration Management System, IBM Rational Synergy. He wants to track one of his applications, based on several nsfs. I couldn't find anything on the Interwebs about this.

Do you have an idea of how to link a Notes application to a configuration management system? I'm kinda stumped.

Comment: Note to others... This should not be closed as off-topic. The OP is referring to tracking development of applications built for Lotus Notes, using Rational Synergy, which is a tool for supporting software development teams.

Comment: Thanks Richard. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I studied this with an expert in IBM Rational Synergy. The only way that seems practical to me would be to use a special plug-in which they have developped. But I wouldn't want to fiddle around with the Domino Designer either.

They also talked of the possibility of saving 'snapshots' of the design (i.e. save ntfs of the design on a regular basis), but I was recalcitrant to use that since really Notes Databases should always be in a notes-controlled environment.

Bottom line, IBM Rational Synergy does not look like a good fit for doing source control management of Notes Databases. I would definitely go with Subversion or even better with git.